# unable to set content-encoding to gzip in tomcat Server

Tags: web, tomcat6, content-encoding

I'm having issue with **response header in webpage**...My server.xml is having below details,but not getting "**content-encoding**" in "**Response-header**"

```
<Connector compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/css,text/javascript, application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
compression="on"
compressionMinSize="128"
connectionTimeout="20000"
noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
port="8080"
redirectPort="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" />
```

I just wanna make sure that,

1].only changing in **server.xml** is enough?

2].do i have to do any changes in **web.xml** also?